# How can I create tabs and subtabs in Dash?

Tags: tabs, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create two tabs with two subtabs each in Dash but I'm having problems.

Here is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash()


# Create a Dash layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        html.H1('My Dashboard')
    ),
    dcc.Tabs(id="tabs", value='Tab1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab 1', id='tab1', value='Tab1', children =[

            dcc.Tabs(id="subtabs1", value='Subtab1', children=[
                dcc.Tab(label='Sutab 1', id='subtab1', value='Subtab1'),
                dcc.Tab(label='Sutab 2', id='subtab2', value='Subtab2'),
            ]),

        ]),
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab 2', id='tab2', value= 'Tab2', children=[

            dcc.Tabs(id="subtabs2", value='Subtab4', children=[
                dcc.Tab(label='Sutab 4', id='subtab4', value='Subtab4'),
                dcc.Tab(label='Sutab 5', id='subtab5', value='Subtab5'),
            ]),

        ])
    ])
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When I run this application the subtabs in the first tab work as expected. However, I can't navigate to any subtabs in the second tab. Why is this happening? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, with Dash you would need to assign two separate callbacks and then check the values, and return the respective output when trying to do this.

It doesn't change the layout on the page whatsoever. That way you can check the values of the tabs and assign the desired callbacks (in this case traversing between tabs/subtabs).

The following code should achieve what you are looking to do :).

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = dash.Dash()


# Create a Dash layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        html.H1('My Dashboard')
    ),
    dcc.Tabs(id='tabs', value='Tab1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab 1', id='tab1', value='Tab1', children =[
        ]),
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab 2', id='tab2', value='Tab2', children=[
        ])
    ])
])

@app.callback(Output('tab1', 'children'),
              [Input('tabs', 'value')])
def update_tabs(value):
    if value == 'Tab1':
        return dcc.Tabs(id="subtabs1", value='Subtab1', children=[
            dcc.Tab(label='Subtab 1', id='subtab1', value='Subtab1'),
            dcc.Tab(label='Subtab 2', id='subtab2', value='Subtab2'),
        ]),

@app.callback(Output('tab2', 'children'),
              [Input('tabs', 'value')])
def update_tabs(value):
    if value == 'Tab2':
        return dcc.Tabs(id="subtabs2", value='Subtab4', children=[
            dcc.Tab(label='Subtab 4', id='subtab4', value='Subtab4'),
            dcc.Tab(label='Subtab 5', id='subtab5', value='Subtab5')
        ]),

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's another way to do it but the problem was that there was a bug which is now fixed.